# !MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an eclipse plugin which opens up a Dialog, with 4 tabs and some heavy content like images, text and buttons attached with event listeners, 
on click of a custom menu item. Everything behaves fine when i click on the custom menu item for first time. When i close the Dialog and try to open it by 
clicking the menu item i get the following exception,

```
ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-07-02 22:50:12.470

!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception

!STACK 0

org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Unsupported or unrecognized format
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:850)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(HandledContributionItem.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.access$7(HandledContributionItem.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem$4.handleEvent(HandledContributionItem.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Unsupported or unrecognized format
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4397)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4312)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4283)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.image.FileFormat.load(FileFormat.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageLoader.load(ImageLoader.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageDataLoader.load(ImageDataLoader.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData.<init>(ImageData.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.<init>(Image.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.createContents(Dialog.java:775)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:791)
    at com.mnee.coeoppt.mtmrktplc.handlers.WindowOpenHandler.execute(WindowOpenHandler.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong with the image you are trying to create in line 95 in `placeIcon` in `ResultPanelImpl`

Comment: Image image = new Image(display, details.getLogo());
        Label logo = new Label(searchResultContent, SWT.PUSH | SWT.BORDER);
        logo.setBounds(5, 5, 80, 80);
        logo.setImage(image);

Comment: @greg-449 if there is something wrong in the code then it should'nt behave correctly for the first time. This exception is seen only when the dialog box is opened for the second time.

Comment: There are many ways your code could misbehave that would only show up on the second run. What does `details.getLogo()` do?

Comment: It returns an inputstream of a png image.

Comment: So are you making sure the input stream is reset to the start of the file on each call to `getLogo`, you will get exactly this error on the second call if you do not.

Comment: Hi @greg-449, how do i make sure that the i/p stream is reset to the start of the file? The i/p stream is read from a method that is present in the jar file.

Comment: Do you dispose the image when closing the dialog? If it is handled by a ImageRegistry etc. you should not manually dispose it.